# How do I cascade two second order butterworth filters

Tags: c, matlab, audio, signal-processing

I've worked out the coefficients for a 2nd order low-pass and highpass butterworth filter.

The coefficients are as follows. I'm implementing this C.

```
float cutoff = 600.00f * M_PI * 2;
float c = 2.0f / sampleRate;
float q = sqrt(2.0f)/2.0f;

g_a1LP = (2.0f * pow(c, 2.0f) - (2.0f * pow(cutoff, 2.0f))) / (pow(c, 2.0f) + ((cutoff*c)/q) + pow(cutoff, 2.0f));

g_a2LP = -(pow(c, 2.0f)  + pow(cutoff, 2.0f) - (cutoff*c)/q ) / (pow(c, 2.0f) + ((cutoff*c)/q) + pow(cutoff, 2.0f));

g_b0LP = 1.0f;
g_b1LP = 2.0f;
g_b2LP = 1.0f; 

g_a1HP = (2.0f - (2.0f * pow(cutoff, 2.0f))/ pow(c, 2.0f)) / (1.0f + (2.0f/sqrt(2.0f)) * (1.0f/c) * cutoff + (pow(cutoff, 2.0f) / pow(c, 2.0f)));

g_a2HP = -(1.0f - (2.0f/sqrt(2.0f) * 1.0f/c * cutoff) + pow(cutoff, 2.0f)/pow(c, 2.0f)) / (1.0f + (2.0f/sqrt(2.0f)) * (1.0f/c) * cutoff + (pow(cutoff, 2.0f) / pow(c, 2.0f)));

g_b0HP = 1.0;
g_b1HP = -2.0;
g_b2HP = 1.0;
```

I now have to make a 4th order Linkwitz-Riley crossover. I know that this is two butterworth's cascaded. I'm not too sure how I should go about this. Do I just multiply the coefficients together? Am I on the right track? If anyone is bothered, do my coefficients look ok? They plotted fine in matlab.

Comment: Might I add I used the bi-linear transform to get those coefficients

Comment: I don't think you can multiply the coefficients, you can multiply the transfer functions in the frequency space. Or you could just run your signal through them sequentially.

Comment: But wouldn't that just attenuate the high frequencies and then the low frequencies or vice-verse?

Comment: Yes it would. Isn't that what you want? To basically create a band-pass filter? That's what cascading a LPF and a HPF will do... are you sure you want to cascade them?

Comment: I am indeed, but I'm trying to create a crossover network. They'll both have the same cutoff.

Comment: Sorry, I'm also quite new to DSP.

Comment: In a crossover netwirk the two filters are not cascaded. Instead, the same signal is applied to the two filters, in parallel. The output of each filter gives you the high and low frequencies respectively (each to be sent to a different loudspeaker). See for example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_crossover)

Comment: But I'm trying to create a 4th order Linkwitz-Riley crossover filter, which is two 2nd order butterworth's cascaded. Confusing.

Comment: Maybe that means two 2nd order LP butterworths in parallel with two 2nd order HP butterworths. I think the penny has dropped.

Answer (score 4):

In order to create a 4th order high-pass (resp. low-pass) Linkwitz-Riley filter, you have to cascade 2 *identical* second order high-pass (resp. low-pass) Butterworth filters.

With the filters polynomial, it means :

Butterworth filter :

```
h = b0 + b1.X + b2.X**2 / a0 + a1.X + a2.X**2
```

Linkwitz-Riley filter :

```
h' = h**2
```

So if your implementation allows it, you can simply square the Butterworth filter.

If you want to have the Linkwitz-Riley digital filter coefficients, you can :

- Find them by developing the following equation :

  ```
  (b0 + b1.X + b2.X**2) ** 2 = (b0' + b1'.X + b2'.X**2 + b3'.X**3 + b4'.X**4)
  ```

  It will give you 5 coefficients b0' ... b4' as functions of b0 ... b3 (and similarly a0' ... a4' as functions of a0 ... a3), that you can implement into your code.
- Use Matlab or Python

  Here is an example function in Python using scipy.signal, which returns the numerator and denominator Linkwitz-Riley coefficients for digital filter.

  ```
  import scipy.signal as sig
  def linkril(filter_order, w_center, btype='lowpass', analog=False):
     butter_order = int(filter_order / 2.)
     numbut, denbut = sig.butter(butter_order, w_center,
                             btype = btype, analog=analog)
     num = np.convolve(numbut, numbut)
     den = np.convolve(denbut, denbut)
     return(num, den)
  ```

Comment: After a bit of maths : b0' = b0**2, b1'=2*b0*b1, b2'=b1**2+2*b0*b2, b3'=2*b1*b2, b4'=b2**2

Answer (score 3):

Why not using

- [Matlab](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/signal/ref/dfilt.cascade.h): if you could afford it (not free)
- [SciPy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.cascade.html) if you are ready to try Python (free)

They propose to do such operation in 2 lines of code in Python

```
from scipy.signal import butter
# generate the coefficients (discrete time) of a 4 order butterworth bandpass filter, where low cutoff frequency is 0.3 the Nyquist frequency and the high cutoff is 0.4 the Nyquist frequency
butter(4, [0.3, 0.4], 'band')
```

This will output the following coefficients:

```
>>> (array([  4.16599204e-04,   0.00000000e+00,  -1.66639682e-03,
     3.25816475e-19,   2.49959523e-03,  -3.25816475e-19,
    -1.66639682e-03,   0.00000000e+00,   4.16599204e-04]), array([  1.        ,  -3.30057727,   7.28008314, -10.20570426,
    10.95189946,  -8.30658348,   4.82226759,  -1.77664475,   0.43826514]))
```

Comment: I'm doing a real time dsp project, so it has to be done in C. Cheers though.

Comment: Okay, I understand better now. So my answer is not helpful. However, I know that to get the cascaded filter (4th order) you'll have to make the convolution of the 2 filters coefficients (numerators and denominators. Because cascading filters is a multiplication in the frequency domain, it's equivalent to a convolution in the time domain. The filter coefficients you have are the impulse (time domain) response of your filter. You should maybe ask on dsp.stackexchange.com for the details.

Answer (score 0):

RawBean is right in his comment...

First of all, in order to create Linkwitz Riley filter (the same applies to both lowpass or highpass), you have to cascade two ***identical*** filters, like Aporee mentions. Now, this in conjunction with RawBean's comment means that you have to convolve the coefficients. This can be done separately for the numerator and the denominator and the final results will correspond to the numerator and the denominator coefficients of the Linkwitz-Riley coefficients you are seeking.

If you have a look at Aporee's example the convolution function is used to calculate the final coefficients. You could very well use this code snippet to get your coefficients and if the implementation will be a static crossover filter you can even hardcode them.